# how to include more options for built-in options?

Tags: plotting, functions, options

I can a self-defined function for plotting. There is a built-in option `AspectRatio`. I want to include a few more choices for convenience, eg.

```
ratio1 = (yrange[[2]]-yrange[[1]])/(xrange[[2]]-xrange[[1]])
ratio2 = 2*(yrange[[2]]-yrange[[1]])/(xrange[[2]]-xrange[[1]])
ratio3 = (yrange[[2]]-yrange[[1]])/(xrange[[2]]-xrange[[1]])/3
```

other than the standard choices of `Automatic` and `Full`. How to do that so that `AspectRatio->ratio1` becomes a valid input?

Comment: in your case it will be `1`, `2` and `1/3` right?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly is not working? `AspectRatio->ratio1` works just fine for me, given some arbitrary ranges.

Comment: the three ratios are just examples (for course I can just type 1, 2 1/3). I mean I have already calculated a few more complicated ratios that will depend on a few parameters of the input function. I don't want to explicitly calculate them every time I call my self-defined plotting function, and so I want to include them in the optional arguments 'AspectRatio' so that when I just type in 'ratio1' it will automatically calculates that particular ratio inside the function itself.

Comment: In short, I want to put the above codes inside the function, and I can just choose which ratio I want by specifying the argument of 'AspectRatio', but currently it only accepts the built-in `Automatic' and `Full`, something I want to extend.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, I will just demonstrate a simple, straight forward ways with which you might experiment.

First we set up a global variable that assigns *aspect ratio functions*:

```
$aspectRatioFunctions = Function[ func,
    Switch[ func,
        "ratio2", Function[ {p1,p2}, 2 p1/p2 ],
        "ratio3", Function[ {p1,p2}, p1 / (3 p2) ],
        _ , Function[ {p1, p2}, p1/p2 ] (* ratio1 as Default *)

    ]
];
```

We can now use this in a simple graphics function or whatever custom function you want to build upon:

```
Options[ myGraphics ] = {
    "AspectRatioFunction" -> "ratio1"
};

myGraphics[ graphics_List, aspectPars_ , 
    opts : OptionsPattern[{ myGraphics, Graphics }] ] := With[
    {
        aspectRatio = Apply[
            $aspectRatioFunctions@OptionValue["AspectRatioFunction"],
            aspectPars
        ]
   },
   Graphics[
       graphics,
       Evaluate@FilterRules[ {opts}, Options[Graphics] ], (* more robust *)
       AspectRatio -> aspectRatio
   ]
]

gr = { Red, Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}] }

myGraphics[ gr, { 1, 1 }, AspectRatioFunction -> "ratio2", Imagesize -> Tiny ]
```

[image: Ratio2]

Comment: This is merely a toy example to demonstrate the principle, of course.

Comment: Note, that using `FilterRules` makes this more robust; the `Evaluate` is not needed here but may be for functions like `Plot` with `HoldAll` and the like.

Comment: @Physicist Would your maybe care to accept? Thank you. ;-)